# drag and drop in fabric using anuglar not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for an angular project where I am uploading image it worked but in my current scenario I was able to click the image and preview in canvas. But What I am trying is Drag and drop Scneario.

Here is my html

```
<img id="testImage" draggable="true"  class="images-item-upload" *ngFor='let url of urls' [src]="url.url"  (click)="addImageOnCanvas(url.url);"/>
```

After upload the image when i try to drag i am getting error

```
core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
at EditorComponent.push.xD4D.EditorComponent.handleDropOnCanvas (editor.component.ts:1041
```

Here is my ts code for click event

```
        fabric.util.addListener(document.body, 'keydown', (opt) => {
        // do not invoke keyboard events on input fields
        if (opt.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
            return;
        }
        // if(opt.repeat) return; // prevent repeating (keyhold)

        const key = opt.which || opt.keyCode;

        this.handleKeyPress(key, opt);
    });

    handleDragStart(event): boolean {
    this.dragObject = event.target;
    return false;
  }
    handleDragOverCanvas(event): boolean {
         event.stopPropagation();
         return false; // prevenDefault;
    }
```

Comment: Try a safe navigation operator... `[src]="url?.url"`

Comment: @Bruno no still same issue